# How do I make a single shot of espresso with a semi-automatic machine?

Tags: espresso, extraction

I just bought this Barista express from Breville. How long is the extraction time for singe shot, 9 gramme coffee?

Also i did a double shot, setting is at 7 and grind amount in the middle... how do I determine the grind amount?

I understand the basics for double - 19gramme of coffee and around 25mp extraction time... it see,s this 7 and middle works.

How about the single shot?

Answer (score 1):

In general, aim for 2 to 2.5 times the amount of beverage in your cup to the used coffee. If you use 9g of coffee in, aim for 18-23g out. The brew time stays the same. If you compare a single basket to a regular double basket you can see that it's narrower at the bottom, this is intended to restrict flow so you have approximately the same brew time using the same grind size but less coffee.

A brew time of 25-30 seconds is what you should aim for but it's not something you absolutely have to follow. It very well may be that your coffee tastes great at 36 or 23 seconds, it's just a ballpark.

From your question it seems that you're somewhat familiar with brewing espresso but still a beginner. There are a lot of good YouTube videos on this, made by people far more competent and eloquent than me. I think [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTFsBqhpLes&list=PLxz0FjZMVOl3MuAzK5l3gjakoOGrmK8fP) on understanding each variable in brewing espresso is a good start if you're interested.

Answer (score -2):

Halve the dose and the brew time to halve the output volume. If you're pulling 19g doubles with 25s extraction, start with 9.5g singles with 12.5s extraction time. Don't change grind setting or anything else. That should put you close to your double shots. Adjust from there if necessary.

Comment: 12.5s is too low and going to yield an incredibly sour shot of espresso.